# Why is it not possible to create horizontal string array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

If I try to create a string array as follows, I will result in a concatenated string (or 1x6 array?).

```
>> [ 'A1' 'A2' 'A3']
ans = A1A2A3
```

What I expect to obtain is an array of string with 3 elements like `['A1' 'A2' 'A3']`.

If I try to first create a vertical string array and transpose it, i will get:

```
>> transpose([ 'A1'; 'A2'; 'A3'])
ans =

AAA
123
```

This is so different from python in creating a list of string. I don't know why don't 'A1', 'A2' and 'A3' stay separately but rather concatenate together. It seems there is some principles behind I don't quite understand. Hope someone can explain. Thanks!

Comment: You said it yourself in the question: it is different than creating a **list** of strings. The `[` and `]` symbol are for **array** concatenation. There is no base _list_ type in Matlab, but the only types able to store elements of different lengths are the [`cell arrays`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python, you have a `list` that contains `str` instances.

```py
A = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
type(A)
# <type 'list'>

type(A[0])
# <type 'str'>
```

In MATLAB, an `array` is not a datatype in and of itself because technically all data types are inherently arrays. For example `'A1'` is a 2-element array of  type `char`.

When you enclose multiple multi-char strings using `[]`, the values are concatenated together and the output will also be a `char`. In your case, this concatenates all of your input char arrays into a single 6-element character array.

```
A = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'];
class(A)
%   char

size(A)
%   1   6
```

If you want an array where each element is non-scalar (and potentially different datatypes), you need to use a cell array

```
A = {'A1', 'A2', 'A3'}
```

Comment: So a square bracket `[]` is only used to concatenate rather than to create a datatype. The datatype created during concatenation by `[]` depends on the datatype of the input inside the `[]`. In contrast, the curly bracket `{}` can be used to create cell array which is a kind of datatype. Please correct if I make any mistake.

Comment: @KenT Yup! That's precisely what it does.